# XMPP onRoster name attribute not appearing

Tags: javascript, xmpp, openfire, strophe

I am building an XMPP chat application using strophe.js (javascript) and openfire as server.

The application is working fine; however, I cannot manage to display the name attribute for the Rosters gathered. Either the name is undifined or it displays the jid of the Roster.

Where is the name stored in the XMPP database and how could I change it? Should I add the name  in the memeber table where all xmpp users are store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is in Javascript:

```
var iq = $iq({type: 'set'}).c('query', {xmlns: 'jabber:iq:roster'}).c("item",  {jid:'romeo@example.net',name:'MyRomeo'});
con.sendIQ(iq);

con.send($pres({to: 'test@test.com', type: "subscribe"}))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set your contact's name using strophe.js. Just send this query:

```
<iq from='juliet@example.com/balcony'
       id='gb3sv487'
       type='set'>
     <query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'>
       <item jid='romeo@example.net'
             name='MyRomeo'/>
     </query>
   </iq>
```

Strophe.js:

```
var query = $iq({type: 'set'}).c('query', {xmlns: 'jabber:iq:roster'}).c('item', jid: 'jid@domain.com', name: 'JoeDoe')     
        connection.sendIQ(query, function success(response) {
            console.log(response); // for debugging purposes
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, I am still having trouble writing it in javascript

Comment: @mikek how do i get the current set display on nick name using stophejs